# How to send parameter to MVC3 action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textbox, submit

I have texbox and button (`<a>` tag) in  side by side `<li>` tag:

```
<li>
    @Html.TextBox( "keyword", "", new { @placeholder = "Search", @class = "inputclass" } )
</li>
<li>
  <a href="@Url.Action( "Index", "Home", new { keyword = ?????? } )" >
     <img src="@Url.Content( "~/Content/images/search.png" )"  width = "83px"  height="29px"  />
     <p class="searchClass">Search</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Index action has keyword parameter. Ho to send keyword in textbox to Index action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li>
    @Html.TextBox( "keyword", "", new { @placeholder = "Search", @class = "inputclass" } )
</li>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:send();" >
     <img src="@Url.Content( "~/Content/images/search.png" )"  width = "83px"  height="29px"  />
     <p class="searchClass">Search</p>
  </a>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function send(){
    var textboxValue = $('input[name=keyword]').val();
    window.location.href = "/Home/Index?keyword=" + textboxValue;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the textbox in a form and have the link submit the form to the action method you are interested in.  Look into @html.BeginForm for pointers.